# Topic shared on two forums in phpbb

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpbb

I'm looking for solution how to joining two forums working on two different databases. The catch is, that those forums need to still working on their own databases, but sharing one common topic.

Both forum are 3.0.10 & working on the same server,

I have no clue how to start.

I know exactly, that this is possible to create db connection like: $db2 and session working on $db1 and $db2 in the same time. But no clue what next?..

Comment: IMHO the easiest way would be to simple edit both posts in the two forums at the same time, instead of trying to hack the forum into displaying a thread from a different database.

Comment: That would be to much to work do, it has to work "remotely" :(